# Auto sized column in jsGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

I am playing with jsGrid, and have only one problem left to solve:
When i define the grid columns, i specify width for all columns but one.

```
fields: [
    { name: "Name", type: "text", title: "Naziv"  },
    { name: "Mbs", type: "text", width: 24, title: "MBS"  },
    { name: "PB", type: "text", width: 23, title: "PB"  },
    { name: "OIB", type: "text", width: 34, title: "OIB"  },
    { name: "Country", type: "text", width: 35, title: "Država"  },
    { name: "City", type: "text", width: 35, title: "Grad"  },
    { name: "ActiveFrom", type: "text", width: 28, title: "Od"  },
    { name: "ActiveTo", type: "text", width: 28, title: "Do"  },
    { name: "Active", type: "checkbox", width:10, title: "A" }
],
```

The problem is that the first field is set to 100px, and then, browser calculates width of all columns based on specified width, which results in column width changing when browser window width changes.

I have tried setting that column width to "auto" and "*", but then, that column takes 90% of the table, and width of other columns is 10px (but css shows the width i defined earlier)

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Comment: I would specifiy the width with percentage (width: "20%")? Sum it up to 100% then

Comment: That still wouldn't resolve the problem, at the behavior would be the same. Expected behavior is that columns with specified width value are fixed width, and columns with no value specified are left to browser to decide (leaving one column with unspecified width would result in that column filling the remaining table space)

Comment: Ah ok, I know what you mean. Have you tried to specifiy the width as width: "24px" instead of a number?

Comment: jsGrid appends px. But to be on the safe side, i have tried by setting width to "22px" (with each column using the specified value)

Comment: Mmh, maybe a dirty solution would be to set the width via Javascript in the "onDataLoaded" method.

Comment: Hm. i just tried disabling css width on specified column. That results in some weird behavior. The column stretches to 90% of table, and all other columns shrink to 10px.
While waiting to post, i figured whats wrong. as i said before, widths are calculated by browser, and when width of first column is set to *, the rest actually shrink to 24px, 23px, 32px etc.

Comment: Thanks @Bluesight for being my second set of eyes.

Comment: No problem mate, I'm glad you finally found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least one column width must be set to "auto", before trying to render the table.
If no width is set, it defaults to 100px, thus breaking the desired appearance.

Just my luck. I waste a hour on something so trivial, and when i decide to ask here, i find the solution and wish to delete the shame of this question.